# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > Encountered " "-" "- "" at line 4662, column 49. Was expecting: "("

Tags: android

When I build the project I got the following error message :
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

```
 Encountered " "-" "- "" at line 4662, column 49.
  Was expecting:
  "(" ...
```

So I build with stack trace and I got

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task 
':app:processDebugResources'.
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:196)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:50)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:75)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
 Caused by: com.github.javaparser.ParseException: Encountered " "-" "- "" at 
line 4662, column 49.
Was expecting:"(" ...    
at com.github.javaparser.ASTParser.generateParseException(ASTParser.java:9233)
at com.github.javaparser.ASTParser.jj_consume_token(ASTParser.java:9106)
at com.github.javaparser.ASTParser.FormalParameters(ASTParser.java:1292)
at com.github.javaparser.ASTParser.MethodDeclaration(ASTParser.java:1205)
at com.github.javaparser.ASTParser.ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration(ASTParser.java:959)
at com.github.javaparser.ASTParser.ClassOrInterfaceBody(ASTParser.java:865)
at com.github.javaparser.ASTParser.ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration(ASTParser.java:470)
at com.github.javaparser.ASTParser.ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration(ASTParser.java:932)
at com.github.javaparser.ASTParser.ClassOrInterfaceBody(ASTParser.java:865)
at com.github.javaparser.ASTParser.ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration(ASTParser.java:470)
at com.github.javaparser.ASTParser.TypeDeclaration(ASTParser.java:398)
at com.github.javaparser.ASTParser.CompilationUnit(ASTParser.java:203)
at com.github.javaparser.JavaParser.parse(JavaParser.java:111)
at com.github.javaparser.JavaParser.parse(JavaParser.java:158)
at com.github.javaparser.JavaParser.parse(JavaParser.java:177)
at butterknife.plugin.FinalRClassBuilder.brewJava(FinalRClassBuilder.java:36)
at butterknife.plugin.ButterKnifePlugin$applyPlugin$1$1$1.execute(ButterKnifePlugin.kt:34)
at butterknife.plugin.ButterKnifePlugin$applyPlugin$1$1$1.execute(ButterKnifePlugin.kt:15)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:632)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:615)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
... 78 more`
```

It seems the javaparser got an error.
Here my gradle app file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {

compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
defaultConfig {

    applicationId "com.ipwebcom.connect.location.beastchat"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
    jackOptions {
         enabled true
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
productFlavors {
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',
        {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3') {
    // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
    exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-fragment:25.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.6'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:10.2.6'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0'
compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.3.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This project was running well until I used roughike in the layout file.
Below is an example of my layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
   android:id="@+id/fragment_friends_tabLayout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   app:tabMode="fixed" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/fragment_friends-viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fragment_friends_tabLayout"/>

<com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombar_tabs" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any hint will be appreciate.
Thks.

Comment: Butterknife is misconfigured, it seems

Comment: Have you added  this in your buildscript?    Found it on their github page.
                    
`buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
   }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.6.0'
  }
}`

Comment: Thks, I have already done that without success.

Comment: I didn't put this file on the question (sorry) but the classpath was already included in my buildscript.

Comment: Hello,I finally found the error. The error shows up when I have add a resources files mentioned above. I misspelled an id :  android:id="@+id/fragment_friends-viewpager" must be  android:id="@+id/fragment_friends_viewpager". The correction solved everything.